# How to get all classes from an element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the class "is-active" and "is-visbile" that's in the picture. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I know the element has the class but when I try to remove it or even check if it has the class using contains, it doesn't work.

```
 const splideList1 = document.querySelectorAll(".splide-one li")
 splideList1[0].classList.remove('is-active')
 splideList1[0].classList.remove('is-visible')

console.log(splideList1[0].classList)
```

The image is the result of the console.log

[image]

HTML

```
  <ul class="splide__list second-slider">
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_1') ?>" />
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_2') ?>" />
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_3') ?>" />
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_4') ?>" />
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_5') ?>" />
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_6') ?>" />
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_7') ?>" />
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
      <img class="active-img" src="<?php the_field('imagem_8') ?>" />
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Given the mismatch between the collapsed value (`"splide__slide"`) and the value in the expanded view (`splide__slide is-active is-visible`) I would hazard a guess that you're not using dev tools correctly.

Comment: I put in the post the HTML, but it's just a list of li

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to be correct:

```js
const splideList1 = document.querySelectorAll(".splide-one li")

console.log("before", splideList1[0].classList.toString())

splideList1[0].classList.remove('is-active')
splideList1[0].classList.remove('is-visible')

console.log("after", splideList1[0].classList.toString())
```

```html
<ul class="splide-one">
  <li class="is-active is-visible">Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually just need the first matching element, you can use querySelector

```
document.querySelector(".splide-one li").classList.remove('is-active', 'is-visible')
```

if you want to target the first matching item that has those classes, you could use

```
document.querySelector(".splide-one li.is-active.is-visible").classList.remove('is-active', 'is-visible')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried your code on the [Splider](https://splidejs.com/) website's demos from the browser console (I've never worked with it before, just googled "splider" because I figured from the naming convention that it was a plugin).

It works provided that the selector fed into `querySelectorAll` is `".splide__list li"` to match the demos.

Which makes me think that your selector string isn't right.

Is `.splide-one` actually the class on the element containing the slides or should it be an ID? `#splide-one li`?

For diagnostic purposes try `document.querySelectorAll('.is-active.is-visible')` instead -- this will pick up only the active/visible slide. If that works then `.splide-one` is the problem, maybe it's the element's ID you've got there, or maybe its class is `splide__one` or something?